# Convert csv file to map

Tags: scala

I have a csv file containing a list of abbreviations and their full values such that the file looks like the below

```
original,mappedValue
bbc,britishBroadcastingCorporation
ch4,channel4
```

I want to convert this csv file into a Map such that it is of the form

```
val x:Map[String,String] = Map("bbc"->"britishBroadcastingCorporation", "ch4"->"channel4")
```

I have tried using the below:

```
Source.fromFile("pathToFile.csv").getLines().drop(1).map(_.split(","))
```

but this leaves me with an Iterator[Array[String]]

Answer (score 1):

You are close , split provides an array. You have to convert it into a tuple and then to a map

```
Source.fromFile("/home/agr/file.csv").getLines().drop(1).map(csv=> (csv.split(",")(0),csv.split(",")(1))).toMap
```

```
res4: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(bbc -> britishBroadcastingCorporation, ch4 -> channel4)
```

In real life , you will check for existance of bad rows and filtering out the array splits whose length is less than 2 or may be put that into another bin as bad data etc.

Comment: I would rather do this: `map(line => line.split(',')).collect { case key :: value :: Nil => key -> value }.toMap`